$L^q[0,1]$ is a (Baire) first category subset in $L^p[0,1]$

Let $1\leq p<q<\infty$, prove that $L^q[0,1]$ is a (Baire) first category subset in $L^p[0,1]$

There is an answer to this question here. In that answer, I figured out that there are two steps:
(1) $\overline{B}_q(0,c)$ is closed in $L^p[0,1]$;
(2) $\overline{B}_q(0,c)$ has empty interior in $L^p[0,1]$.
But I need to prove it by applying Baire category theorem and uniform boundedness principle respectively. (Because I just learned Baire category theorem and uniform boundedness principle in the functional analysis lesson. )
I have no idea how to construct a family of bounded linear operator and what to prove by using uniform boundedness principle. And I don't know how to use Baire category theorem either.
Could you please give some hints?
